# How to save the whole webpage in PDF file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jspdf

May i ask how to save the whole webpage as PDF file. I already have a script for saving webpage as PDF file but it can't capture the whole webpage. here's the script: My expectation is to save the whole details of webpage

```
   <script>
    function wa(){
            genPDF(0,0);
    }
    function genPDF(x,y){

        var doc = new jsPDF();
        //alert(document.getElementById("paper").clientWidth);//100.26
        var paperwidth = 8.5;
        var paperheight = 11;
        var ppi = parseFloat(document.getElementById("paper").clientWidth)/paperwidth;
        var height = ppi.toFixed(2)*paperheight;//instead of 11 inches
        var numpages = Math.ceil(parseFloat(document.getElementById("paper").clientHeight)/height.toFixed(2));

        window.scrollTo(0,0);
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("paper"),{
            onrendered:function (canvas){
                var x=0;
                while (x<numpages)
                {
                    var y = x*height;
                    window.scrollTo(0,y);
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',5,5);
                    doc.addPage();
                    x=x+1;
                }
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });`enter code here`
    }
  </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: use this https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: You could use `window.print()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print This would show a print screen, and from there you can save the whole page as a PDF

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, but window.print() is good if you have PDF printer driver. my pc has no PDF printer and we are not allow to install any driver. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try to this man

```
  var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);

  var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;    
  var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, There's nothing happen when i used this code. Thank you